# Junit Testing with void method

Tags: java, junit, void

I have to create a JUnit test for the following class, but I cannot do the test for the method `deposit`.

```
public class Account {
    private int balance;
    private float Interest_Rate =10;

    public Account() {
        this.balance = 0;
    }
    public void deposit(int amount) {       
        balance = balance+amount;
    }
}

@Test
public void testdeposit() {
    Account i = new Account();
    assertEquals("Result",75,i.deposit(25));
}
```

Comment: Create a get method to access the balance. Assert the deposit prior to and following the call.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: The test that i wrote check the code would not run,, i am getting an error at the "assertEquals", as the method deposit returns void,, so how do i make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `getBalance()` method in the `Account` class :

```
 public int getBalance(){
      return balance;
    }
```

And use it to do the assertion :

```
@Test
public void deposit(){
    Account i = new Account();
    i.deposit(25)
    assertEquals("Result",25, i.getBalance());
}
```

Generally adding methods that are only used during unit testing may be evaluated and discussed.
But here `getBalance()` appears as unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Testing private fields/methods does not have sense.

In your case, `balance` is 'write-only' variable; it should have public accessor (as written above), or field should be used in other methods like

```
public int income() {
  if(balance == 0 ) return 0;
  if(balance < 100) return 10;
  if(balance < 1000) return 15;
  return 20;
}
```

In this case your test should be like

```
@Test
public void deposit(){
  Account acc = new Account();
  acc.deposit(150);
  assertEquals("Result ", 15, acc.income());
}
```

Don't test implementation; test interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a System.out.println in the method and tell the JUnit test to ask for stdout:

```
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

and then

```
@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
}

@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(null);
}
```

finally

```
assertEquals(<here goes your expected string>, outContent.toString());
```